# mysql events, как удалить вчерашние записи?

Tags: mysql

Добрый день. Подскажите, как правильно составить запрос?  Требуется удалять записи таблицы, которые созданы вчера. Пробовал создавать эвент: 
 `CREATE EVENT del_link
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 24 HOUR
    COMMENT 'Delete old links.'
    DO
      DELETE FROM db_name.table_name WHERE TO_DAYS(date) <> TO_DATE(NOW());`

Результат нулевой. Не уверен нужно ли указывать название БД, по этому и без нее пробовал.

Comment: не знаю на счет событий, но само удаление было бы лучше делать `where date < CURDATE()` ваше текущее условие явно никуда не годится, вы приводите date к количеству дней и сравниваете с датой, а не кол-вом дней

Comment: Пробую другие события создавать, но что-то ничего не отрабатывает

Comment: После доп.проверок выяснилось что данная возможность отключена у провайдера. Пришлось вешать на cron